# Why is my G Suite Gmail favicon blue?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-workspace-for-business

My G Suite Gmail favicon has turned blue. Now it looks like this:
[image]

- What the color change mean? Is is part of a rebranding, or is it supposed to notify users about some special state of Gmail app?
- Is it possible to get back to the original red icon?

Comment: [BuzzFeed: Here's Why Your Gmail Icon Might Be Blue Now](https://www.buzzfeed.com/katienotopoulos/why-gmail-icon-is-blue?utm_term=.aodpyqv917#.fl01VvWBbK)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Google forum it is a bug that is due to the lab "Unread message icon" being enabled.  If you turn off that lab it reverts back to red.  I am not sure what else to tell you and this is definitely annoying.

Comment: Please add the Google forum link.

Comment: It seems to be fixed. Red envelope icon is back again.

Answer (score 0):

Supposedly the developer of the Lab feature, is now favoring blue for Google Apps (G Suite), since most users of G Suite also have a personal (red) account of Gmail too. https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/apps/ZXJvWINKpwI/DIrg7F3FBAAJ